# Como utilizar o which.max em um dataframe em formato longo?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Tenho um `DF` em formato longo e testei o seguinte código:

```
library(tidycovid19) # Pacote do GitHub - https://github.com/joachim-gassen/tidycovid19
library(tidyverse)

updates <- download_merged_data(cached = TRUE)

teste <- updates %>%
  mutate(newCases = confirmed - lag(confirmed, 1),
         newCases = ifelse(newCases < 0, 0, newCases),
         mm7d = rollmeanr(newCases, 7, fill = NA, allign = "left")) %>%
  filter(country == "Australia")

max <- which.max(teste$mm7d)
teste <- teste[teste$date <= teste$date[max],]
```

Este código aplica um filtro para retornar o maior valor de uma média móvel de 7 dias e retira todos os dados posteriores a esse valor. Minha questão é: como posso aplicar esse mesmo código para vários países e plotá-los em um gráfico?

Países que estou usando de exemplo (em código iso3)

```
paises <- c("BRA", "CHN", "USA", "ESP", "AUS", "COL", "ITA")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para fazer o que a pergunta pede

1. Primeiro filtrar por código ISO, obtém-se uma base mais pequena o que é melhor para o que vem a seguir.
2. Agrupar por código ISO, os cálculos serão feitos país a país.
3. Calcular os novos casos e a média móvel de 7 dias. Neste último caso, a função apropriada é `rollmean`, já que estamos a alinhar à esquerda.
4. Filtrar só os valores anteriores ao máximo de `mm7d`.
5. Finalmente, para o gráfico bastam três colunas. Se for necessário ficar com todas as colunas, remover esta linha.

A seguir o gráfico é um gráfico de pontos e linhas simples.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidycovid19)

updates <- download_merged_data(cached = TRUE)
paises <- c("BRA", "CHN", "USA", "ESP", "AUS", "COL", "ITA")

teste <- updates %>%
  filter(iso3c %in% paises) %>%
  group_by(iso3c) %>%
  mutate(newCases = confirmed - lag(confirmed),
         newCases = ifelse(newCases < 0, 0, newCases),
         mm7d = zoo::rollmean(newCases, 7, fill = NA, allign = "left")) %>%
  filter(date <= date[which.max(mm7d)]) %>%
  select(iso3c, date, newCases)

ggplot(teste, aes(date, newCases, colour = iso3c)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]